# double quotes found in json array

Tags: java, arrays, json

a json array is as given below

```
var data = [
            {label:'gggg',data: [[(new Date('2011/12/01')).getTime(),53914],[(new Date('2012/1/02')).getTime(),32172],[(new Date('2012/2/03')).getTime(),824],[(new Date('2012/4/04')).getTime(),838],[(new Date('2012/6/05')).getTime(),755],[(new Date('2012/7/06')).getTime(),0],[(new Date('2012/8/07')).getTime(),0],[(new Date('2012/9/08')).getTime(),0],[(new Date('2012/10/09')).getTime(),0],[(new Date('2012/11/10')).getTime(),0],[(new Date('2012/12/11')).getTime(),0],[(new Date('2012/12/11')).getTime(),0]]}

        ];
```

in java class for creating the above similar json, i'm using the following code given below.
**but the problem is there is a double quotes  in each** `"(new Date(2012/12/01)).getTime()"`

can anyone please tell me how to remove those double quotes

```
 Query q1=session.createQuery("FROM VendorMonth");
          List li1=q1.list();


          String supname="",tempsupname;  
          JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
          JSONArray jsonarrmast = new JSONArray();
          List s=new ArrayList();

          JSONArray finals=new JSONArray();
          JSONArray finalarray = new JSONArray();
          for(int i=0;i<li1.size();i++)
          {
            HashMap hmap = new HashMap();
            VendorMonth venmonth=(VendorMonth) li1.get(i);
            tempsupname=venmonth.getId().getSupplierName();
            if(i==0){
                supname=venmonth.getId().getSupplierName(); 
            }

            if(!supname.equals(tempsupname)){
                obj.put("label", supname);
                obj.put("data", jsonarrmast); 
                jsonarrmast = new JSONArray();
                s.add(obj);
                finalarray.put(obj);
                obj = new JSONObject();
                supname=venmonth.getId().getSupplierName();

                JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray();
                String date=venmonth.getId().getYearnam()+"/"+venmonth.getId().getMonthnam()+"/01";
                String ss=new String("(new Date("+date+")).getTime()");
                jsonarr.put(ss);
                jsonarr.put(venmonth.getId().getRentalrate());
                jsonarrmast.put(jsonarr);
            }
            else
            {
                JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray();
                String date=venmonth.getId().getYearnam()+"/"+venmonth.getId().getMonthnam()+"/01";
                String ss=new String("(new Date("+date+")).getTime()");
                jsonarr.put(ss);
                jsonarr.put(venmonth.getId().getRentalrate());
                jsonarrmast.put(jsonarr);

            }

            if(i==(li1.size()-1)){
               obj.put("label", supname);
               obj.put("data", jsonarrmast); 
               jsonarrmast = new JSONArray();
               s.add(obj); 
               finalarray.put(obj);
            }


          }
```

but i'm getting the output as given below

```
[{"data":[["(new Date(2012/12/01)).getTime()",10976.23],["(new Date(2013/1/01)).getTime()",51213.8200000002],["(new Date(2013/2/01)).getTime()",32172.31],["(new Date(2013/3/01)).getTime()",824.600000000001],["(new Date(2013/4/01)).getTime()",838.000000000001],["(new Date(2013/5/01)).getTime()",755.780000000001],["(new Date(2013/6/01)).getTime()",50877.12]],"label":"Weather Ford"},{"data":[["(new Date(2012/12/01)).getTime()",24368.3],["(new Date(2013/1/01)).getTime()",1968.76]],"label":"Logan Tools"},{"data":[["(new Date(2012/12/01)).getTime()",3425.63],["(new Date(2013/1/01)).getTime()",731.75]],"label":"Pioneer tools"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to create a JSON object that matches your declaration, because that's not a JSON object: it's Javascript code.

Once that Javascript code is ran, however, `data` will contain an object that can be serialized to JSON, and I'm assuming that's what you're trying to achieve.

What your Java code does is add a `String` to a `BasicDBArray` - the fact that it's interpreted as a `String` should not come as a surprise. By the same token, when you add an int or a boolean, they're added as ints and booleans, not strings.

What you *actuall* want to put in your BasicDBArray is the value that `new Date('2011/12/01').getTime()` would return if interpreted as Javascript: the number of milliseconds between 1970/01/01 and 2011/12/01. I'm assuming you can retrieve that through something like `venmonth.getId().getDate().getTime()`, or however it is you retrieve a `Date` instance from your `venmonth` object.